# nodejs - how to write a client that connects to a nodeJS Server and receives broadcast message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have the following nodeJS Server that seems to work fine. I would like to write a client that receives message from the server and invokes some JS based on the message.

The steps involved are:

1. User accesses the url `http://server.xyz.com:8080/pa`
2. nodeJS Server receives that call and broadcasts to the connected clients that `pa` is the api call received.
3. nodeJS Clients that are connected to the server invoke some JS related to the `pa` action.

My questions are:

```
1. How do I make sure the server broadcasts that message like Step 2?
2. How do I write a client that performs Step 3 above.
```

For the client, I am seeing a lot of references to socket.io, but I am not sure what's the best framework in this case.

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  request.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    response.statusCode = 400;
    response.end();
  });
  response.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });

  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  var body=[];
  if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/pa') {
    response.end(JSON.stringify({"action": "pa"}));
  }
  else if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/pi') {
    response.end(JSON.stringify({"action": "pi"}));
  }
   else {
    response.statusCode = 404;
    response.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the clients are also in Node.js then you should be able to set up a webhook/push service. Webhooks are used in every major API today, they are extremely prevalent in Slack's and Microsoft's. The following is inspired by Microsoft's Office 365 [push](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations) and [streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-streaming-rest-operations) services APIs.

Add a route that clients can POST to, let's call this `/subscribe`. In the request body to the `/subscribe` route, they include a url, we'll call it the paReceiverUrl.

If a client wishes to be notified when someone else messages the `/pa` endpoint, a client can send a request to the `/subscribe` endpoint and include the location to notify them at - the `paReceiverUrl` (along with any other info, probably some auth data). You should store the subscribed clients' information in non-volatile storage to be safe, have a database do this for you or simply write it to a file until it gets more complex.

Now your `'/pa'` route becomes something more like this (your Step 2):

```
if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/pa') {
    // Send response to the request sender
    response.end(JSON.stringify({"action": "pa"}));
    // Get subscribed clients' information
    var subscribedClients = <Read from file or db>
    // Broadcast
    for(var i = 0; i < subscribedClientsUrls.length; i++) {
      // Send them a request at subscribedClients[i].paReceiverUrl
    }
}
```

Now for your Step 3, the clients simply just need to have their server accepting requests at their `paReceiverUrl` and there they can invoke whatever JS they want.

If you need it to be more real-time then I would go with the web sockets protocol to set a persistent HTTP connection to stream data over.